# I have deleted the registration from site-packages but still it is not showing me import error

Tags: python, django, django-registration

`urls.py` in my main app [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ucZg.png)

My project structure, it can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfLGk.png) that there is no module named registration

Still when i run the server it doesn't give me any error any runs as it was before deleting. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**EDIT:**
The problem is solved now. The VIRTUAL_ENV path in bin/activate was wrong. I just edited it and it worked.

Comment: You may have to restart the server before you see the import errors.

Comment: I did that but still it is not showing import errors.

Comment: remove `*.pyc` file and try restarting the server

Comment: I deleted all the 6 .pyc files namely - __init__.pyc, forms.pyc, settings.pyc, urls.pyc, views.pyc, wsgi.pyc, still it is working fine.

Comment: Perhaps the code isn't running in the virtual environment in which you think it is.

Comment: But I am seeing the log messages in the terminal whenever I move across the website.

Comment: Add `import registration` then print or log `(registration.__file__)`. It should show you where `registration` is being imported from.